# Isolated scope fails to listen to changes in values

Tags: angularjs

The isolated scope is setup to listen to changes in the containing scope. However this fails.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.foo = { bar: 'hello' };

})
.directive('test-dir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '='  
      },
      link: function($scope) {
        console.log($scope.name);

        $scope.$watch('name', function(newValue) {
          console.log(newValue);
        }, true);

      }
    };

});
```

The template is something like this:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{foo.bar}}!</p>
    <input ng-model="foo.bar">

    <hr/>
    <testDir name='foo'></testDir>
  </body>
```

What am I missing here ?

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/kldjQrPPBFvlq7ZSOAeb?p=info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the scope you just mixed up the naming of your directive:

```
.directive('testDir', function() {...
```

html:

```
<test-dir name='foo'></test-dir>
```

The directive wasn't working in the first place

Comment: Note that the HTML can use the `testDir` format also. The important factor here is the naming of the directive in the `directive()` call.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan are you sure about that? as far as i know you can't use the camelCase naming in the html, you have to substitute it with `:`, `-`, or `_`

Comment: I just tested and you are correct. I could have sworn I'd used camel casing at one point, but that was more than a week ago, so my memory gets fuzzy :).

Answer (score 0):

there should be double quotes and not single ones: `name="foo"`, not `foo`

also camel case naming is used in declaration. When referring to it, you should use the dash separated names.

So when you have a directive like

```
directive('testDir', function() {...});
```

Then you use it like

```
<test-dir>
```

And not `<testDir>`

Answer (score 0):

directive name:

```
.directive('testDir', function() {........
```

html name:

```
<test-dir name='foo'></test-dir>
```

also change in scope name to:

```
name: '=?'
```

if it doesn't work:

```
name: '@'
```